# Pandas - Blanking out values of one column if value of another column has a specific value

Tags: python, pandas-loc

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Status': ['','To Do', '','Completed', 'To Do', 'In Progress', 'Completed'], 
'Date': ['','9/1/2022','','12/5/2019','8/12/2020','4/19/2020','12/31/2018']})
```

I want to blank out the Date column for those rows where the Status is anything but "Completed". Using .loc, I am getting an error.

```
df = df.loc[df['Status'] != 'Completed', 'Date'] = ''

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Comment: As specified by the answer bellow you don't need to assign the result of `df.loc[]` to `df` as it will modify your data frame in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo here:

```
df = df.loc[df['Status'] != 'Completed', 'Date'] = ''
```

Should be

```
df.loc[df['Status'] != 'Completed', 'Date'] = ''
```

Comment: That's not a typo, I'm using df = to redefine the DataFrame based on the .loc. Regardless, this doesn't resolve the error.

Comment: First code chunk can be removed as it could be mistaken as a valid answer.

Comment: An alternative expression which does the same thing is `df['Date'][df['Status'] != 'Completed'] = ''`

Comment: Oh I see that now. I was used to redefining df, like when I just wanted it to reflect a certain value in a column. But this worked, many thanks!